# Define a class for latitude and longitude in C++ using boost::units and spheroidal coordinates

Tags: c++, validation, coordinate-system, boost

I am trying to write a class that defines latitude and longitude in C++ using `boost::units` and normalized spheroidal coordinates.  I want to throw an exception if the class is constructed outside the bounds of the normalized spheroidal coordinates.  Incidentally I thought about using `boost::geometry` but when I read [this forum discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-list/h_JE1Pw9k9Q) it looked like converting between using `boost::units` and `boost::geometry` was not straightforward, so I am just making the below and am wondering if this is a good path to go down.

```
#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/plane_angle.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/angle/degrees.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_units/angle/radian.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_units/angle/degree.hpp>
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>

namespace units = boost::units;
namespace si = units::si;
namespace constants = boost::math::constants;

class Latitude
{
private:
  units::quantity<si::plane_angle> angle;

public:
  Latitude(units::quantity<si::plane_angle> angle) : angle(angle)
  {
    assert (angle <= ( constants::half_pi<double>() * si::radians));
    assert (angle >= (-constants::half_pi<double>() * si::radians));
  }

  const units::quantity<si::plane_angle> value()
  {
    return angle;
  }

};

class Longitude
{
private:
  units::quantity<si::plane_angle> angle;

public:
  Longitude(units::quantity<si::plane_angle> angle) : angle(angle)
  {
    assert (angle <= ( constants::pi<double>() * si::radians));
    assert (angle >= (-constants::pi<double>() * si::radians));
  }

  const units::quantity<si::plane_angle> value()
  {
    return angle;
  }

};
```

Comment: Where does `assert()` come from?  Did you miss `#include <cassert>`?  If so, that's not a good form of run-time error handling.